# Geronimo double slash "//" in urls with application having context root "/"

Tags: java, geronimo

I am using Geronimo version 2.2.1.  I am trying to deploy a `war`-file with its context-root set to `/` in `geronimo-web.xml`.

Now every time I navigate my application all the urls are rewritten with double forward slashes.

Examples:

```
http://mydomain:8080//login.jsp
http://mydomain:8080//home.html
```

How can I change the configuration so that only a single slash appears.  I have found similar questions but none of them seem to have answers.

Comment: AFAIK, the root context root is the empty string, not `/`.

Comment: @JB Nizet - The correct root context is "/" according to the default root context when Geronimo is installed (welcome-tomcat page).  However, the empty string has the same behavior as "/".

Comment: I notice if I put a leading "/" in front of the url in the anchor a single "/" is shown as I want.  This surely is not desirable though because if the context-root was later changed to be anything else all the links would be broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with Geronimo 2.2.1.  You can see the details at [Geronimo issue 6171](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GERONIMO-6171).

The issue has been fixed and will be part of the next release.  I have verified that everything works as expected using the latest snapshot of Geronimo 2.2.2.